# Uncountably many 0-1 valued sequences

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence taking values in $\{0,1\}$. Is it true that the set of these sequences for which
$$
\frac{1}{n}(x_1+\cdots+x_n) \to 0
$$
is uncountable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: Try finding a way to transform an arbitrary $\{0,1\}$-sequence into a $\{0,1\}$-sequence with "most" of its entries equal to $0$.

Comment: Every such sequence, if you put a decimal point in it, corresponds to a number between 0 and 1 in binary.  Conversely, every number between 0 and 1 can be written in binary and thus gives a sequence of 0's and 1's.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the sequences where $x_k=0$ unless $k$ is a perfect square. There are an uncountable number of these and
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{n=\infty}\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^nx_k
&\le\lim_{n=\infty}\frac1n\left\lfloor\sqrt{n}\right\rfloor\\
&=0
\end{align}
$$
for any of these sequences.